# multiple nested if statements not calculating

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I'm trying to get this payslip calculator to run multiple if statements nested in eachother.

The conditions it requires to meet are as follows:

If the monthly gross pay is 2000 for example
and the last letter of the NI code is A

to work out a national insurance allowance you do the gross pay divided by 4.
2000 / by 4 = 500. Meaning that the NI band is a2.

The sum then is "gross * a2" (as seen on the variables listed at the top of the code)

This then displays the result as "Your NI deduction:??"

I'm struggling to get the if statements to run if a different letter is inputted.. For example "B"

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
function computeNet() {
<!--NI Codes - use https://www.gov.uk/national-insurance-rates-letters/contribution-rates for updates on NI rates--!>
//NI Code A//
var a1 = 0;
var a2 = 0.12;
var a3 = 0.12;
var a4 = 0.02;
//NI Code B//
var b1 = 0;
var b2 = 0.0585;
var b3 = 0.0585;
var b4 = 0.02;
//NI Code C//
var c = 0;
var d1 = 1.4;
var d2 = 0.106;
var d3 = 0.12;
var d4 = 0.02;
//NI Code E//
var e1 = 0;
var e2 = 0.0585;
var e3 = 0.0585;
var e4 = 0.02;
//NI Code J//
var j1 = 0;
var j2 = 0.02;
var j3 = 0.02;
var j4 = 0.02;
//NI Code L//
var l1 = 1.4;
var l2 = 0.02;
var l3 = 0.02;
var l4 = 0.02;

var gross = document.getElementById('gross').value;
var tax_code = document.getElementById('tcode').value;
var ni_code = document.getElementById('ni').value;

var allowance = ((gross - ((tax_code * 10)/12)));
var ni_allowance = (gross / 4);


         if (ni_code = "A") {
             if (ni_allowance > 111 && ni_allowance < 153) {
                 ni_minus = (gross * a1);
             }
             else if (ni_allowance > 153.01 && ni_allowance < 770) {
                 ni_minus = (gross * a2);
             }
             else if (ni_allowance > 770.01 && ni_allowance < 805) {
                 ni_minus = (gross * a3);
             }
             else {
                 ni_minus = (gross * a4);
             }
        if (ni_code = "B") {
             if (ni_allowance > 111 && ni_allowance < 153) {
                 ni_minus = (gross * b1);
             }
             else if (ni_allowance > 153.01 && ni_allowance < 770) {
                 ni_minus = (gross * b2);
             }
             else if (ni_allowance > 770.01 && ni_allowance < 805) {
                 ni_minus = (gross * b3);
             }
             else {
                 ni_minus = (gross * b4);
             }
         }
         document.getElementById('ni_deduction').innerHTML = "Your NI deduction:"+ni_minus;
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Your Monthly Gross Pay: £<input id="gross" type="number" onChange="computeNet()"></p>
<p>The numerical part of your tax code: <input id="tcode" type="number" onChange="computeNet()"></p>
<p>last letter of your NI code: <input id="ni" type="text" onChange="computeNet()"></p>

<h2 id="gross_pay"></h2>    
<h2 id="paye-deduction"></h2>
<h2 id="ni_deduction"></h2>
<h2 id="net_pay"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/n384noLk/

I look forward to your help

Comment: You should use double equal marks to make a comparison.currently it's just assigning the values. `if(ni_code == "A")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "B" needs to be moved out of If "A".

Because it is nested, you skip the If "B" statement completely if ni_code doesn't equal "A".

```
if (ni_code == "A") {
    if (ni_allowance > 111 && ni_allowance < 153) {
        ni_minus = (gross * a1);
    } else if (ni_allowance > 153.01 && ni_allowance < 770) {
        ni_minus = (gross * a2);
    } else if (ni_allowance > 770.01 && ni_allowance < 805) {
        ni_minus = (gross * a3);
    } else {
        ni_minus = (gross * a4);
    }
} elseif (ni_code == "B") {
        if (ni_allowance > 111 && ni_allowance < 153) {
            ni_minus = (gross * b1);
        } else if (ni_allowance > 153.01 && ni_allowance < 770) {
            ni_minus = (gross * b2);
        } else if (ni_allowance > 770.01 && ni_allowance < 805) {
            ni_minus = (gross * b3);
        } else {
            ni_minus = (gross * b4);
        }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n384noLk/2/

Answer (score 0):

Equality is tested by == in JavaScript therefore should be:

```
if(ni_code == "A")
```

and

```
if(ni_code == "B")
```

Also you are not closing your first if statement so it is seeing the

```
if(ni_code == "B")
```

as a continuation of the nested if. You need another } after:

```
else {
    ni_minus = (gross * a4);
}
```